# Searching Index of Value in Excel Sheet with Python

Tags: python, excel, indexing

I'm trying to find the Index of an value.
I'm using pandas to read in an excel file with different Sheets and columns.
Now I'm trying to find the Index of an Value, using enumerate.

```
df = pd.read_excel('filename',sheet_name='1',usecols=[col1,col2,...], header=0, skiprows=[1])
df1 = pd.read_excel('filename',sheet_name='2',usecols=[1,2,...],header=0,skiprows=[1])
indices=[i for i,value in enumerate(df)if value=='11:03:45']
print("New Indices List:"+str(indices))
```

This Code return no error, but it returns only this:
`[]`
Can someone help me? I tried different things, but nothing worked so far.

Thanks!

Comment: try changing `enumerate(df)` to `enumerate(df['time'])` where `df['time']` is the column where your value `'11:03:45'` is located

Comment: @Thekingis007 didn't work either, but thanks for the try!